# Cannot read properties of null React

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, jsx, fetch-api

so I am currently trying to fetch data and return in an input text box for updating (PUT request), but whenever I try to assign the fetched data to a state variable I get a null error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null
```

After some research, I found out that the fetching process (async) takes some time to retrieve the data which explains the null error. So, how do I account for this time period in my state variable declaration? Also feel free to correct me if this error is due to something else.

Here is my code to implement the PUT Request: mind you I imported the useFetch before implementing it

```
function EditStory() {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { data: story } = useFetch(apiUrl + id); //apiUrl is just a placeholder, wont post actual url
const [currentStory, setStory] = useState(story['mData']['mMessage']);

function handleEdit(){
    //  PUT request logic
}
    return (
        <>
            <H1> Edit Story {id} </H1>
            <form onSubmit={handleEdit}>
                <Input type='text'
                    value={currentStory}
                    onChange={(e) => setStory(e.target.value)}/>
                <Button type='submit' value='Submit'> Update </Button>
                <CancelButton type='reset' value='Reset' onClick={() => navigate(-1)}> Cancel </CancelButton>
            </form>
        </>
    )
```

}

Here is my useFetch component:

```
function useFetch(url) {

const [data, setData] = useState(null);

// Retrieve story
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => 
            response.json()
        )
        .then(data => { // story received in json format
            setData(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {console.log(error)})
}, [url]) //adding url here makes it so that whenever the url changes, useEffect will rerun 

return { data }
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react useEffect hooks with axios cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62207658/react-useeffect-hooks-with-axios-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with this line `story['mData']['mMessage']`
Since story is going to be `null` initially and we are trying to access it.

We could use an optional chaining here in this place that would return `undefined` if the value is not found.

```js
const [currentStory, setStory] = useState(story?.['mData']?.['mMessage']);
```

Or we could use a shorthand and operator to avoid the error

```js
const [currentStory, setStory] = useState(story && story['mData'] && story['mData']['mMessage']);
```

Comment: So after testing your two suggestions, here's what came about. the optional chaining returned undefined as you suspect, and the shorthand returns null. What I ended up doing instead was copying and pasting the usefetch code into my editstory components and just doing the fetch there. I'll be using this short-term solution until I can figure out the solution to the problem. Thank you