# useState() showing empty array always when page load and doesn't add the fetch data in second useState(), shows undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

When I run the useState it is running twice where the first time is giving the empty array[] and the second time is showing the fetch data.

```js
const [configuration, setConfiguration] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  getMailinfo();
}, []);
function getMailinfo() {
  axios
    .get(`${appLocalizer.apiUrl}/wcs/v1/wcs_mail_active`, {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "X-WP-NONCE": appLocalizer.nonce,
      },
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      setConfiguration(response.data);
    });
}

console.log(configuration);
```

```js
{
    "mailactive": true,
    "ownermail": "msa.demo@gmail.com",
    "username": "msa.demo@gmail.com",
    "password": "168463517FKJKT1EE13B4CE44B9A90",
    "host": "smtp.email.com"
}
```

It run twice; first [] empty array then the data

Now If I use my fetch data inside another useState its always shows undefined as useState getting empty array first time.

```jsx
const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(configuration.ownermail);
console.log(toggleState); // undefined

return (
  <>
    <div>Documentation from react:- {configuration.ownermail}</div>
    <div>Second run:- {configuration.toggleState}</div>
  </>
);
```

Here 'Documentation from reacting:-' loading first then a after few seconds It shows  "Documentation from reacting:- myvalue"

the second div shows nothing and the console its undefined.

My App.js

```jsx
return (
  <div className="wcs_plug" id='wcs_plug_start'>
    <WCSTab /> {/* I have already removed the React.StrictMode */}
  </div>
);
```

Can anyone please help here ?? Thanks In advance;

So in short, When I run the useState it is running twice where the first time is giving the empty array[] and the second time is showing the fetch data.
Now If I use my fetch data inside another useState it always shows undefined as useState getting an empty array the first time.
I want my fetch date to send inside the second useState and also want to run the return only once with valid data. It should not delayed to show the fetch data

Comment: In that case you can use some initial data instead of an empty array or consider having a loading state till the data arrives which is the most common ones ....

Comment: Thanks for the response. As its an array and fetch data from the rest API, If I set any initial value then on page load It will show those initial data for a few second, and the most important thing the second useState not taking the fetch data, it return always undefined but then it will show only my initial value but not the actual value which I am getting from rest API.So my goal is not full fill.

Comment: _"It run twice; first [] empty array then the data"_... why is that a problem? Your state is an empty array on the first render, then the `setConfiguration(response.data)` triggers a re-render and it has your data in it. Use conditional rendering to show things only when you have data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react useEffect hooks with axios cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62207658/react-useeffect-hooks-with-axios-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Comment: Already tried those: 
    `<div>Second run:- {toggleState ? toggleState : "Loading.."}</div>
    <div>Second run 2:- {toggleState && toggleState}</div>`

Here 
The second div always returns undefined so the value is set to : Loading or empty. 

`const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(configuration && configuration.ownermail);`

pass this conditional statement on the second useState but not fixed.

Comment: You shouldn't be initialising a state variable from another. Your `toggleState` will never change. Use a [memo hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) if you want something derived from state... `const toggleState = useMemo(() => configuration.ownerEmail, [configuration])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Phil, useMemo fixed my problem.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react"

const toggleState = useMemo(() => configuration.ownermail, [configuration])

return (
    <>
    <div>Second run 0:- {toggleState}</div>
    <div>Second run 1:- {toggleState ? toggleState : "Loading.."}</div>
    <div>Second run 2:- {toggleState && toggleState}</div>
    </>
  )
```

Now all conditions are working